# Is it possible to build for 4" iPhone displays only?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to build my app for iPhone 5, 5s, 5c only. I don't want to build for 3.5 displays (iPhone 4 and 4s).

I've looked through the build settings but I see no such setting. I looked up Apple's documentation for the "Required device settings" property, but there's nothing related to this. I wondered if I could force it by changing the architecture but they're all armv7 devices.

Is it possible? I'm using Xcode 5 with the iOS 7.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, and if you do steps in your code to disable functionality of smaller devices, Apple will reject your app. Remember, Apple sold iPhone 4 until last year and is still selling iPhone 4S. iOS7 is supported on iPhone 4 and 4S. It would be a great disservice to potential users to disable support for their devices.